# How to convert this specific integral from cartesian to polar

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

How to convert this surface integral from $x$ and $y$ coordinates to $r$ and $\theta.$ $$\int_0^a\int_0^a\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{3/2}}dx dy$$ This integral is to get electric field due to a plane from a point charge.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In order to convert you need: 1) convert limits; 2) convert integrand; 3) convert elemntary area $dxdy$. Try to do it step-by-step.

Comment: Formula looks like normal component of electric field intensity formed by uniformly charged side of cube size $a$ in one of other vertices of cube. Note, that there is also tangential component of electric field intensity in this point.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1245303/934187 ,and try to solve your question

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4621060/949989) could also be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $dxdy$ is the area of an infinitesimal strip of length and width $dx$ and $dy$ respectively. Now think about an infinitesimal strip of length $dr$ at a distance $r$ from origin and angular width $d\theta$. What would be area? It should be $rdrd\theta$. Thus we would replace $dxdy$ in the integral by $rdrd\theta$ and $x=r\cos \theta$, $y=rsin \theta$ and integrate it over the given square region. We will partition the square region into two parts, the one which lies below and diagonal and the one which lies above the diagonal and calculate the integral as the sum of integrals over these two regions. But the function is symmetrical about the diagonal $x=y$ and hence the two integrals would be same. Thus

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^a\int_0^a\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{3/2}}=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\frac{a}{\cos\theta}}\frac{1}{(r^2+a^2)^{3/2}}rdrd\theta
\end{eqnarray}